# How to add the shadow to my box as the picture shows below

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,decorations.pathmorphing}

\newcommand{\syBrisse}[6][\textwidth-2\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}-4pt]
  {
    \begin{center}
      \par\bigskip
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[rounded corners, 
            text width=#1, 
            align=justify,
            inner sep=8pt, 
            outer sep=0] 
           (one)
           {\medskip\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\vspace*{22pt}\par#6}};

      \node[anchor=north east,
            align=center, 
            minimum height=20pt,
            inner xsep=5pt] 
           (two) at (one.north east) 
           {#5 \hspace*{0.5mm}};

      \path[top color=#3,
            bottom color=#3,
            middle color=#3!35,draw=#3]
           ($(one.north west)+(2cm,-4.5pt)$)    [rounded corners=3pt] --
           ($(two.north west)+(-16.2pt,-4.5pt)$)                      --
           ($(two.south west)+(-4pt,0pt)$)       [sharp corners]      --
           (two.south east)                      [rounded corners]    --
           (two.north east)                                           --
           (one.north west)                      [sharp corners]      --
           ($(one.north west)+(0cm,-1cm)$)       [rounded corners]    --
           ($(one.north west)+(1.2cm,-1cm)$)                          -- cycle;

      \node[text=#2,
            anchor=north west,
            align=center, 
            minimum height=20pt,
            text height=2ex,
            inner sep=2cm, 
            inner ysep=3pt] 
           (three) at ($(one.north west)+(0,0pt)$)
           { #4};

      \node[text=white,
            anchor=north east,
            align=center, 
            minimum height=20pt,
            inner sep=8pt,
            inner ysep=6.5pt] 
           (for) at ($(one.north east) +(0,1.5pt)$) 
           { #5\hspace*{0.8mm}};

      \node[text=white,
            anchor=north west,
            align=center, 
            minimum height=5pt,
            inner sep=8pt,
            inner ysep=3pt] 
           at (one.north west) 
           {\small{\bf{ add to}}};
      %%%%%%matwiya

      \path[draw=#2,line width=1pt]
           (one.south west) [rounded corners] --
           (one.south east) [rounded corners] --
           (one.north east)                   --
           (one.north west) [rounded corners] -- cycle;

      \foreach \x in {10,20,...,100}
        {
          \path[opacity=\x*0.01]
               ($(one.north west)+(0cm,-1.03cm)$)                  [rounded corners=3pt,draw=gray!\x]   --
               ($(one.north west)+(1.2cm,-1.03cm)$)                                                     --
               ($(one.north west)+(2cm,-6.5pt+\x/100)$)            [rounded corners=3pt,draw=gray!\x]   --
               ($(two.north west)+(-17.3pt+\x/100,-6.5pt+\x/100)$) [rounded corners=3.5pt,draw=gray!\x] --
               ($(two.south west)+(-5.3pt+\x/100,-1.9pt+\x/100)$)                                       --
               ($(two.south east)+(-0.4pt,-1.9pt+\x/100)$);
        }

      \path[draw=white,
            line width=1.1pt]
           ($(one.north west)+(.3cm,-1cm)$)      [rounded corners=3pt]   --
           ($(one.north west)+(1.2cm,-1cm)$)                             --
           ($(one.north west)+(2cm,-5.2pt)$)     [rounded corners=3pt]   --
           ($(two.north west)+(-17.3pt,-5.2pt)$) [rounded corners=3.5pt] --
           ($(two.south west)+(-4.3pt,-0.6pt)$)                          --
           ($(two.south east)+(-0.4pt,-0.6pt)$);

      \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \path[fill=#3!5]
             (one.south west) [rounded corners] --
             (one.south east) [rounded corners] --
             (one.north east)                   --
             (one.north west) [rounded corners] -- cycle;

        \path[opacity=0.5, 
              top color=#3!5,
              bottom color=#3,
              middle color=#3!30]
             (one.south west) [rounded corners]                 --
             (one.south east) [sharp corners]                   --
             ($(one.south east)+(0ex,0.8cm)$)                   --
             ($(one.south west)+(0ex,0.8cm)$) [rounded corners] -- cycle;
      \end{pgfonlayer}

      \node[draw=white,
            line width=2pt,
            decorate,
            decoration={random steps,
                        amplitude = 1.2pt},
            middle color=white,
            right color=orange,
            middle color=red, 
            left color=yellow,
            text=white,
            anchor=north west,
            align=center,
            rectangle,
            outer sep=8pt,
           ] 
           at ($(one.north west)+(-0.4cm,-0.3cm)$) 
           {{\textbf{\ \  ur book\ }}};

      \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{center}}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\begin{document}

\syBrisse[11.6cm]{blue!85!black}{blue!90!black}{{\bf }}{\bf theorem}{
 $\mathbb{C }$   $\dfrac{1}{z}$
.
\\
 $z$  $\mathbb{C }$ $\dfrac{1}{z}$
.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that does not rely on special fonts? This would increase the number of people who can potentially help you.

Comment: it's so  easy to get rid of all these fonts becouse it is 'nt  important

Comment: Well, if that's so easy, why don't you just do it? I believe I could write an answer if it were not for the fonts that prevent me from even copying your MWE.

Comment: No probleme  take this code I have removed the special fonts

Comment: @WalidTex It greatly helps if you format your code so that it is more readable.  It could help even more if you were to comment what each portion is intended to do.  I've cleaned up your code to improve its readability and made a few corrections, such as your syntax for `\foreach`.  I've also removed dependencies on packages that are not relevant to your issue.  Anyhow, for an FYI for future reference.  Folks here are pretty quick to respond and help.  It's a very friendly community.  The easier you make it for use to read your code, the quicker our response can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the shadow below the orange thing your could use `drop shadow` from `\usetikzlibrary{shadows}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newcommand{\syBrisse}[6][\textwidth-2\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}-4pt]
  {
    \begin{center}
      \par\bigskip
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[rounded corners, 
            text width=#1, 
            align=justify,
            inner sep=8pt, 
            outer sep=0] 
           (one)
           {\medskip\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\vspace*{22pt}\par#6}};

      \node[anchor=north east,
            align=center, 
            minimum height=20pt,
            inner xsep=5pt] 
           (two) at (one.north east) 
           {#5 \hspace*{0.5mm}};

      \path[top color=#3,
            bottom color=#3,
            middle color=#3!35,draw=#3]
           ($(one.north west)+(2cm,-4.5pt)$)    [rounded corners=3pt] --
           ($(two.north west)+(-16.2pt,-4.5pt)$)                      --
           ($(two.south west)+(-4pt,0pt)$)       [sharp corners]      --
           (two.south east)                      [rounded corners]    --
           (two.north east)                                           --
           (one.north west)                      [sharp corners]      --
           ($(one.north west)+(0cm,-1cm)$)       [rounded corners]    --
           ($(one.north west)+(1.2cm,-1cm)$)                          -- cycle;

      \node[text=#2,
            anchor=north west,
            align=center, 
            minimum height=20pt,
            text height=2ex,
            inner sep=2cm, 
            inner ysep=3pt] 
           (three) at ($(one.north west)+(0,0pt)$)
           { #4};

      \node[text=white,
            anchor=north east,
            align=center, 
            minimum height=20pt,
            inner sep=8pt,
            inner ysep=6.5pt] 
           (for) at ($(one.north east) +(0,1.5pt)$) 
           { #5\hspace*{0.8mm}};

      \node[text=white,
            anchor=north west,
            align=center, 
            minimum height=5pt,
            inner sep=8pt,
            inner ysep=3pt] 
           at (one.north west) 
           {\small{\bf{ add to}}};
      %%%%%%matwiya

      \path[draw=#2,line width=1pt]
           (one.south west) [rounded corners] --
           (one.south east) [rounded corners] --
           (one.north east)                   --
           (one.north west) [rounded corners] -- cycle;

      \foreach \x in {10,20,...,100}
        {
          \path[opacity=\x*0.01]
               ($(one.north west)+(0cm,-1.03cm)$)                  [rounded corners=3pt,draw=gray!\x]   --
               ($(one.north west)+(1.2cm,-1.03cm)$)                                                     --
               ($(one.north west)+(2cm,-6.5pt+\x/100)$)            [rounded corners=3pt,draw=gray!\x]   --
               ($(two.north west)+(-17.3pt+\x/100,-6.5pt+\x/100)$) [rounded corners=3.5pt,draw=gray!\x] --
               ($(two.south west)+(-5.3pt+\x/100,-1.9pt+\x/100)$)                                       --
               ($(two.south east)+(-0.4pt,-1.9pt+\x/100)$);
        }

      \path[draw=white,
            line width=1.1pt]
           ($(one.north west)+(.3cm,-1cm)$)      [rounded corners=3pt]   --
           ($(one.north west)+(1.2cm,-1cm)$)                             --
           ($(one.north west)+(2cm,-5.2pt)$)     [rounded corners=3pt]   --
           ($(two.north west)+(-17.3pt,-5.2pt)$) [rounded corners=3.5pt] --
           ($(two.south west)+(-4.3pt,-0.6pt)$)                          --
           ($(two.south east)+(-0.4pt,-0.6pt)$);

      \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \path[fill=#3!5]
             (one.south west) [rounded corners] --
             (one.south east) [rounded corners] --
             (one.north east)                   --
             (one.north west) [rounded corners] -- cycle;

        \path[opacity=0.5, 
              top color=#3!5,
              bottom color=#3,
              middle color=#3!30
              ]
             (one.south west) [rounded corners]                 --
             (one.south east) [sharp corners]                   --
             ($(one.south east)+(0ex,0.8cm)$)                   --
             ($(one.south west)+(0ex,0.8cm)$) [rounded corners] -- cycle;
      \end{pgfonlayer}

      \node[draw=white,
            line width=2pt,
            decorate,
            decoration={random steps,
                        amplitude = 1.2pt},
            middle color=white,
            right color=orange,
            middle color=red, 
            left color=yellow,
            text=white,
            anchor=north west,
            align=center,
            rectangle,
            outer sep=8pt,
            drop shadow={shadow scale=1.05},
           ] 
           at ($(one.north west)+(-0.4cm,-0.3cm)$) 
           {{\textbf{\ \  ur book\ }}};

      \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{center}}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\begin{document}

\syBrisse[11.6cm]{blue!85!black}{blue!90!black}{{\bf }}{\bf theorem}{
 $\mathbb{C }$   $\dfrac{1}{z}$
.
\\
 $z$  $\mathbb{C }$ $\dfrac{1}{z}$
.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @WalidTex You're welcome! And thanks for changing your question to remove all the special fonts!